# MassTransit , how to use multibus with autofac

Tags: autofac, masstransit

I have two consumers one that gets data from bus 1, and it will then publis to Bus 2.
I followed the instructions to use multibus in :https://masstransit.io/documentation/configuration/multibus#multibus-configuration

I set up ISecondbus interface as per link and configure mySecondConsumer:

```
    container.AddMassTransit<ISecondBus>(x =>
    {
       x.AddConsumers(typeof(mySecondConsumer).Assembly);
       x.AddBus(context => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
         {
            cfg.Host(new Uri(busOptions.ConnectionString));
            cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(_env.EnvironmentName.ToLower() + "-my-queue", ec =>
            {
               ec.ConfigureConsumer<mySecondConsumer>(context);
               ec.UseScheduledRedelivery(r => r.Intervals(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),   
               TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10)));
               ec.UseMessageRetry(r => r.Immediate(5));
            });
         }));
    });
```

In myfirstConsumer(which publishes to mySecondConsumer) i inject it in like this :

```
    public myfirstConsumer(
                Bind<ISecondBus, IPublishEndpoint> publishEndpoint,
                ILogger<myfirstConsumer> logger,)
               {           
                  _publishEndpoint = publishEndpoint;
                  _logger = logger;
               }
```

When i run it autofac throws an exception
---> (Inner Exception #1) Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown while activating DMS.Service.Documents.Consumer.DocumentBridgeUpdateRecievedConsumer.
2024-01-22 19:11:39        ---> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'Service.Documents.Consumer.myfirstConsumer' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
2024-01-22 19:11:39 Cannot resolve parameter 'MassTransit.ExtensionsDependencyInjectionIntegration.Bind`2[Common.Store.ISecondBus,MassTransit.IPublishEndpoint] publishEndpoint' of constructor 'Void .ctor(MassTransit.ExtensionsDependencyInjectionIntegration.Bind`2[DMS.Common.Store.ISecondBus,MassTransit.IPublishEndpoint], Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`1[DMS.Service.Documents.Consumer.DocumentBridgeUpdateRecievedConsumer])'.

It looks like it doesnt like the way i inject the  Bind<ISecondBus, IPublishEndpoint> publishEndpoint.

Not sure what i can do?

How can i configure and call my Secondbus in MassTransit using Autofac

Comment: MultiBus requires MassTransit v8, which [doesn't support Autofac](https://masstransit.io/support/upgrade#version-8) directly.